# set cookie in jquery dialog and show selected value on page after submit with postcode

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter, cookies

i'm making a page where people have to fill in their postcode so they can search factories in a near area.

i used the jquery modal dialog where people have to enter their postcode and click submit. then i want a cookie to be set so when the user enters the site for a second time, the postcode is still set. so he can search for factories directly.

i have this popup:
[image: dialog]

the people have to fill in their postcode there and then click opslaan (save)

Here you can see the mainpage with the search function. people can search on different kilometers.

[image: search and main]

I want a label or something with the filled in postcode so people can search with their postcode.

EDIT:

my jquery dialog code:

```
$(function() {

$( "#dialog" ).dialog(
{ 
show: "slow",
modal: "true",
width: 600,
show: "fold",
hide: "fade",
resizable: false,
draggable: false,
buttons: [ { id: "go", text: "Opslaan", click: function() { $( this ).dialog( "close" ); } } ],
open: function(event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();  }});
$(".ui-widget-overlay").css({background: "#000", opacity: 0.8});
});
```

When i put this code:

```
<input type="text" id="postcode" value="" name="search"/>
<button id="go">Opslaan</button>
```

In the div for the jquery dialog. it does not work.

```
<div id="dialog" title="Welkom bij OostWestRegioBest.nl">
  <p>Vul hier uw postcode in en druk op opslaan:</p>
  <br />


</div>
```

Comment: What's exact problem here? You can't set cookies using jQuery or you can't read cookies? BTW, it would be much more useful if you showed us code instead of screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend jquery cookie here: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

You would then do

```
$.cookie('postcode', $('#postcode').val());
```

to set it, and this to read it:

```
if(typeof $.cookie('postcode') !== 'undefined'){
    $('#postcode').val($.cookie('postcode'));
}
```

So, for example, if you have the following HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="postcode">
<button id="go">Go!</button>
```

Then your JS would look like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //story the cookie on button press
    $('#go').click(function(){
            $.cookie('postcode', $('#postcode').val());        
    });

    //retrieve the cookie on load if it's not undefined
    if(typeof $.cookie('postcode') !== 'undefined'){
            $('#postcode').val($.cookie('postcode'));
    }
});
```

Here is a functioning example: http://tinker.io/38617/4

Comment: Awesome. and how do i view this in a input field? or label?

Comment: I added a link to a functioning example with an input and button

Comment: What's happening when you try? Post your code or send link :-)

Comment: i have a jquery dialog and when i put the code in there it does not work. it does when i implement it on the page itself, not the dialog

Comment: In my header. on the same page as where i put the code for my dialog

Comment: i still can't get it to work. it does not work anymore on the mainpage

Comment: please create a tinker.io with the full code- I dont know what youre doing wrong without the full code

Comment: I could not get it working so i just used php setcookie. that worked fine for me :) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
function setCookie(sName, sValue) {

    if(getCookie(sName)==null) {
        if(isValidUsrURL(path)) {
            document.cookie = sName + "=" + escape(sValue) + "; " +
                "path=/; ";
        } else {
            domainname='.example.com';
            document.cookie = sName + "=" + escape(sValue) + "; " +
                "path=/; domain=" + domainname + "; ";
        }
    }


}

function getCookie(sName) {

    // cookies are separated by semicolons
    var aCookie = document.cookie.split("; ");
    for (var i=0; i < aCookie.length; i++) {
        // a name/value pair (a crumb) is separated by an equal sign
        var aCrumb = aCookie[i].split("=");
        if (sName == aCrumb[0]) {
            return unescape(aCrumb[1]);
        }
    }
    // a cookie with the requested name does not exist
    return null;

}

function deleteCookie(sName) {
    document.cookie = sName + "=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT";
}


//EG usage : 
//deleteCookie('brochTabURL', '/', '.example.com');
//setCookie('brochTabURL', document.location.href );
//setCookie("COOKIE_CHECK","YES");
//var loginId = getCookie("COOKIE_CHECK");
```