# save input in dialog and show in form on mainpage using cookies

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, cookies, jquery-dialog

I asked a question to set a cookie in an input field and show it on an inputfield on the mainepage.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15225225/set-cookie-in-jquery-dialog-and-show-selected-value-on-page-after-submit-with-po
```

It does not show anything. my jquery.cookie.js works fine because i'm using more cookies.
maybe this is the problem? maybe the first code overrides the next code?
i don't know if that is relevant.

---

I have a jquery dialog that pops up when a user visit my site.
http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl/

you have to fill in your postcode and then click to continue to the website.
the code for this is:

```
<div id="dialog" class="hidden" title="Welkom bij OostWestRegioBest.nl">

Vul hier uw postcode in: <br /><br />
<input type="text" id="postcode">

</div>
```

and my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //story the cookie on button press
    $('#go').click(function(){
            $.cookie('postcode', $('#postcode').val());  
    });

    //retrieve the cookie on load if it's not undefined
    if(typeof $.cookie('postcode') !== 'undefined'){
            $('#postcode').val($.cookie('postcode'));
    }
});
```

Now i would like to print the saved cookie in the text input on the main page form.
[image: printscreen of input field]

Hope someone can provide a nice solution for this.

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't this just be easier to POST the value to the controller and retrieve it in your view file?

Comment: How do i do that? i'm still new to Codeigniter.

Comment: When you click "go", where does the page submit to?

Comment: To a search page that isn't finished. but 'go' is my function to save/set the cookie.

Comment: the id="go" i mean :)

Comment: You'll want to post that to a "search" controller and method. You can access the data from there and send it to your view file.

Comment: do i have to store it in the database then?

Comment: No. Please read the CI docs to understand the MVC pattern and passing data from controllers to views.

Comment: hm i fixed it another way. i did it with setcookie() that way it worked good enough forme. thanks anyway :)

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out, but please see my answer for the correct way to do this. You will run into issues by doing this with cookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the discussion in comments didn't seem to change the OPs mind, I'll post here for future reference if anyone visits this.

You should not use cookies to send POST data. Many users turn cookies off in their browsers and that will prevent your application from receiving the data you need it to.

In this case, being Codeigniter, you should submit the data to the controller, declare the value in a variable, and send that variable to your next view.

Search View:

```
// Feel free to use CI's form helper here as well
<form method="POST" action="/search"
    // whatever your form is
    <input type="text" id="postcode" name="postcode">
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Search Controller:

```
function index() {
    // search logic

    // Grab your postcode value and declare it in a variable
    data['postcode'] = $this->input->post('postcode');

    // Load your next view and pass the data
    $this->load->view('search_results', $data);
}
```

Results View:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $postcode; ?>">
```

Also for future reference, Codeigniter has methods to handle setting cookies so you do not have to do it with a separate jQuery library. If you need the postcode variable for the entire session of your user using your site, that would be the better method.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer. i will try this when i come across such a some problem/project.